# Linq To Sql Row not found or changed

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I have the following code which actually is quite simple:

```
   foreach (var pr in b.Receipes)
   {
       var br = prod.Where(o => o.ProductID == pr.ProductID).FirstOrDefault();
       string entity = "piece";
       if (pr.SelectedEntity != null)
           entity = pr.SelectedEntity.Type;
       if (br != null)
       {
           br.TotalQuantity = br.TotalQuantity - b.Amount * pr.QuantityUsage;
           br.Amount = (Int32)(br.TotalQuantity / br.UnitQuantity);
       }
       dc.SRAddInvoiceDetailsConsumable(inv.InvoiceID, pr.ProductID, entity, pr.QuantityUsage, b.Amount);
       dc.SubmitChanges();
   }
```

So I execute this stored procedure which inserts record in a table with a for loop and on the second cycle i get the error row not found or changed.

The table structure is like:

```
[Id] INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[InvoiceID] INT NOT NULL,
[ProductID] INT NOT NULL,
[Entity] NVARCHAR(300) NULL,
[QuantityUsage] float NOT NULL,
[Amount] int NOT NULL
```

The stored procedure:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SRAddInvoiceDetailsConsumable]
    @InvoiceID INT,
    @ProductID INT,
    @Entity NVARCHAR(300),
    @QuantityUsage float,
    @Amount INT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO SRInvoiceDetailsConsumables
    (InvoiceID, ProductID, Entity, QuantityUsage, Amount)
    VALUES
    (@InvoiceID, @ProductID, @Entity, @QuantityUsage, @Amount)
END
```

Things that did not worked for me following previous posts for the error.

1.The dbml structure is extacly the same as the table.

2.I replaced the dbml with the with the server tables to re-generate the dbml.

3.In the dbml property of the table i set the property "Update check" to never.

I am passing actual values to the stored procedure there are none null-able values.

I`m running out of ideas any help would be great!

**BIG EDIT:**

I found a solution which works.

```
 if (br != null)
 {
     br.TotalQuantity = br.TotalQuantity - b.Amount * pr.QuantityUsage;
     br.Amount = (Int32)(br.TotalQuantity / br.UnitQuantity);
     dc.Refresh(System.Data.Linq.RefreshMode.KeepChanges, br);
 }
```

The problem was not in the stored procedure as I initially thought.

Comment: what is inside in stored procedure?probably the error is there.

Comment: I updated my question.